# Magento Indexing Issue

Tags: php, magento, indexing

I am running a process that does a bunch of updates to a catalog (change names, prices, stock, some custom attributes on items). At the end of the script I have it set to reindex using this code:

```
$processCol = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach($processCol as $process) {
    $process->reindexEverything();
}
```

It runs without error and can place a log to see the indexer codes as they are indexed, however it runs a lot faster than the command line reindex.php file. Also, products that I have set not to be displayed in the data are still shown until I run the reindex from the command line. The reindex in the script seems to be doing something but not updating my products on the front end.

Comment: If you're on a very recent version of Magento, the indexes only run on data that has been changed. It's a possibility that your script doesn't flag those items and the indexes just skip those records (which is probably why it goes a lot faster, because it doesn't do much)

Comment: Yes it is a new version. However I do not see what is in the indexer.php file that indexes everything vs just what is changed. I can run my script and the items on the frontend do not change, however I run the CLI script and it seems to pick up the changes.

Comment: Just for anyone that runs into the same issue I pulled in a lot of the logic from the CLI reindex script into a class and now will reindex like the CLI from code. Copy is a gist here [link](https://gist.github.com/jpratt/9511237)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the last comment by myself. Resolved with a new class.